# como corregir el error “ me hace un update a todas las tuplas y solo necesito a un registro”

Tags: postgresql

requiero hacer un update a la consulta que aparece, pero el resultado que me obtengo, es un update a todas las tuplas de la tabla tiempo, me podrian colaborar para corregir ese error.

```
 WITH data (_vehiculo, _reloj, turno, fecha) AS (
 VALUES(7018, 2, 1, '2019-05-28'::DATE)
 ) 
 ,data_tiempo AS (
  SELECT
  d._vehiculo
 ,rr.nombre_reloj
 ,r.id_ruta
 ,t.create_at
 ,t.id_turnos
 FROM data d
 INNER JOIN turnos t
  ON d.turno = t.numero_turno
    INNER JOIN rutas r
         ON  t.id_ruta = r.id_ruta
    INNER JOIN ruta_relojes rr_j
         ON r.id_ruta = rr_j.id_ruta
    INNER JOIN relojes rr
        ON rr_j.id_reloj = rr.id_reloj
    WHERE TRUE
    AND t.numero_turno = turno
    AND t.vehiculo = _vehiculo
    AND rr.id_reloj = _reloj
    AND t.create_at::DATE = fecha
     )
   UPDATE tiempos 
   SET t.tiempo_marcada = '10:00'
   FROM data_tiempo d_t
```

Comment: Y cual es el único registro que quieres modificar, que id o característica lo identifica?

Answer (score 0):

El error principal que tenés es que no estás vinculando la tabla tiempos con los queries dentro del WITH.

Tembién me parece que es un error referenciar la "tabla" datos desde es segundo query del WITH, dado que los dos estan definidos al mismo nivel, es decir, no creo que datos sea visible para el otro query (que no tiene alias).

Reescribiendo el query me queda así:

```
WITH data (_vehiculo, nombre_reloj, id_ruta, _create_at, id_turnos) AS (
    SELECT 
        d._vehiculo
        ,rr.nombre_reloj
        ,r.id_ruta
        ,r.create_at
        ,r.id_turnos
    FROM
        (VALUES(7018, 2, 1, '2019-05-28'::DATE)) 
              as d (_vehiculo, _reloj, turno, fecha),
        INNER JOIN turnos t
              ON d.turno = t.numero_turno
        INNER JOIN rutas r
              ON  t.id_ruta = r.id_ruta
        INNER JOIN ruta_relojes rr_j
              ON r.id_ruta = rr_j.id_ruta
        INNER JOIN relojes rr
              ON rr_j.id_reloj = rr.id_reloj
        WHERE
              t.vehiculo = d._vehiculo
              AND rr.id_reloj = d._reloj
              AND t.create_at::DATE = d.fecha
) as registros_seleccionados
UPDATE tiempos t
SET t.tiempo_marcada = '10:00'
WHERE t.X in (
    select Xprima from registros_seleccionados
);
```

Faltaría que veas que campo de la tabla tiempos (tiempos.X) se relaciona con los registros seleccionados dentro del WITH a travex del campo registros_seleccionados.Xprima.

*Nota: El query está reescrito en base a lo que posteaste, es decir, sin conocer la estructura real de las tablas. Esto significa que puede no funcionar porque las relaciones están mal definidas, y eso es imposible de ver con los datos de la pregunta.*